# What is the effect of the zero_based parameter in dump_svmlight_file() method in sklearn.datasets?

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm making some classification experiments using sklearn. During the experiments, I'm building csr_matrix objects to store my data and used LogisticRegression classifier on these objects and get some results. 
I dump the data using dump_svmlight_file and the model using joblib. 
But when I then load the data using load_svmlight_file and the model, I obtained (very) different results.

I realized that if I dump the data setting the zero_based parameter to False, I retrieve my original results. What is exactly the effect of this parameter? Is it usual to have different results modifying the value of this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

[The docs are pretty explicit:](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file.html#sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file)

`zero_based : boolean or “auto”, optional, default “auto”`

> Whether column indices in f are zero-based (True) or one-based (False). If column indices are one-based, they are transformed to zero-based to match Python/NumPy conventions. If set to “auto”, a heuristic check is applied to determine this from the file contents. Both kinds of files occur “in the wild”, but they are unfortunately not self-identifying. Using “auto” or True should always be safe.

Your observation seems odd, though. If you dump with `zero_based=False` and load with `zero_based='auto'` the heuristic should be able to detect the right format.
Also, if the wrong format would have been detected, the number of features would have changed, so there would be an error from your classifier.